# Please explain me meaning of gsub("\047|,","",$0) in awk

Tags: bash, awk

From source file, such as;

```
{'PRIMER_INTERNAL_EXPLAIN': 'considered 3, ok 3',
 'PRIMER_INTERNAL_NUM_RETURNED': 0L,
 'PRIMER_LEFT_0': (29L, 22L),
 'PRIMER_LEFT_0_END_STABILITY': 3.86,
 'PRIMER_LEFT_0_GC_PERCENT': 45.45454545454545,
 'PRIMER_LEFT_0_HAIRPIN_TH': 0.0,
 'PRIMER_LEFT_0_PENALTY': 1.1657103482262485,
 'PRIMER_LEFT_0_SELF_ANY_TH': 0.0,
 'PRIMER_LEFT_0_SELF_END_TH': 0.0,
 'PRIMER_LEFT_0_SEQUENCE': 'ATGGCAAATACACAGAGGAAGC',
 'PRIMER_LEFT_0_TM': 58.98043552542492,
 'PRIMER_LEFT_1': (32L, 22L),
 'PRIMER_LEFT_1_END_STABILITY': 4.35,
 'PRIMER_LEFT_1_GC_PERCENT': 45.45454545454545,
 'PRIMER_LEFT_1_HAIRPIN_TH': 31.75767174449885,
 'PRIMER_LEFT_1_PENALTY': 1.2635420728922853,
 'PRIMER_LEFT_1_SELF_ANY_TH': 0.0,
 'PRIMER_LEFT_1_SELF_END_TH': 0.0,
 'PRIMER_LEFT_1_SEQUENCE': 'GCAAATACACAGAGGAAGCCTT',
 'PRIMER_LEFT_1_TM': 58.915214375647565,
 'PRIMER_LEFT_2': (27L, 23L),
 'PRIMER_LEFT_2_END_STABILITY': 3.46,
 'PRIMER_LEFT_2_GC_PERCENT': 43.47826086956522,
 'PRIMER_LEFT_2_HAIRPIN_TH': 0.0,
 'PRIMER_LEFT_2_PENALTY': 1.396379766521477,
 'PRIMER_LEFT_2_SELF_ANY_TH': 0.0,
 'PRIMER_LEFT_2_SELF_END_TH': 0.0,
 'PRIMER_LEFT_2_SEQUENCE': 'TGATGGCAAATACACAGAGGAAG',
 'PRIMER_LEFT_2_TM': 58.735746822319015,
 'PRIMER_LEFT_EXPLAIN': 'considered 479, overlap excluded region 66, GC content failed 18, low tm 100, high tm 139, ok 156',
 'PRIMER_LEFT_NUM_RETURNED': 3L,
 'PRIMER_PAIR_0_COMPL_ANY_TH': 0.0,
 'PRIMER_PAIR_0_COMPL_END_TH': 0.0,
 'PRIMER_PAIR_0_PENALTY': 3.6468465778591295,
 'PRIMER_PAIR_0_PRODUCT_SIZE': 114L,
 'PRIMER_PAIR_1_COMPL_ANY_TH': 0.0,
 'PRIMER_PAIR_1_COMPL_END_TH': 0.0,
 'PRIMER_PAIR_1_PENALTY': 3.744678302525166,
 'PRIMER_PAIR_1_PRODUCT_SIZE': 111L,
 'PRIMER_PAIR_2_COMPL_ANY_TH': 0.0,
 'PRIMER_PAIR_2_COMPL_END_TH': 0.0,
 'PRIMER_PAIR_2_PENALTY': 3.877515996154358,
 'PRIMER_PAIR_2_PRODUCT_SIZE': 116L,
 'PRIMER_PAIR_NUM_RETURNED': 3L,
 'PRIMER_RIGHT_0': (142L, 22L),
 'PRIMER_RIGHT_0_END_STABILITY': 3.33,
 'PRIMER_RIGHT_0_GC_PERCENT': 40.90909090909091,
 'PRIMER_RIGHT_0_HAIRPIN_TH': 39.90652312082375,
 'PRIMER_RIGHT_0_PENALTY': 2.481136229632881,
 'PRIMER_RIGHT_0_SELF_ANY_TH': 0.0,
 'PRIMER_RIGHT_0_SELF_END_TH': 0.0,
 'PRIMER_RIGHT_0_SEQUENCE': 'AGATGGTGAAACCTGTTTGTTG',
 'PRIMER_RIGHT_0_TM': 57.345909180244746,
 'PRIMER_RIGHT_1': (142L, 22L),
 'PRIMER_RIGHT_1_END_STABILITY': 3.33,
 'PRIMER_RIGHT_1_GC_PERCENT': 40.90909090909091,
 'PRIMER_RIGHT_1_HAIRPIN_TH': 39.90652312082375,
 'PRIMER_RIGHT_1_PENALTY': 2.481136229632881,
 'PRIMER_RIGHT_1_SELF_ANY_TH': 0.0,
 'PRIMER_RIGHT_1_SELF_END_TH': 0.0,
 'PRIMER_RIGHT_1_SEQUENCE': 'AGATGGTGAAACCTGTTTGTTG',
 'PRIMER_RIGHT_1_TM': 57.345909180244746,
 'PRIMER_RIGHT_2': (142L, 22L),
 'PRIMER_RIGHT_2_END_STABILITY': 3.33,
 'PRIMER_RIGHT_2_GC_PERCENT': 40.90909090909091,
 'PRIMER_RIGHT_2_HAIRPIN_TH': 39.90652312082375,
 'PRIMER_RIGHT_2_PENALTY': 2.481136229632881,
 'PRIMER_RIGHT_2_SELF_ANY_TH': 0.0,
 'PRIMER_RIGHT_2_SELF_END_TH': 0.0,
 'PRIMER_RIGHT_2_SEQUENCE': 'AGATGGTGAAACCTGTTTGTTG',
 'PRIMER_RIGHT_2_TM': 57.345909180244746,
 'PRIMER_RIGHT_EXPLAIN': 'considered 255, overlap excluded region 66, GC content failed 43, low tm 56, high tm 2, long poly-x seq 41, ok 47',
 'PRIMER_RIGHT_NUM_RETURNED': 3L,
 'SEQUENCE_ID': 'R-chr1:114713809-114714010',
 'SEQUENCE_TEMPLATE': 'TAATATCCGCAAATGACTTGCTATTATTGATGGCAAATACACAGAGGAAGCCTTCGCCTGTCCTCATGTATTGGTCTCTCATGGCACTGTACTCTTCTTGTCCAGCTGTATCCAGTATGTCCAACAAACAGGTTTCACCATCTATAACCACTTGTTTTCTGTAAGAATCCTGGGGGTGTggagggtaagggggcagggagg'}
None
{'PRIMER_INTERNAL_EXPLAIN': 'considered 3, ok 3',
 'PRIMER_INTERNAL_NUM_RETURNED': 0L,
 'PRIMER_LEFT_0': (51L, 23L),
 'PRIMER_LEFT_0_END_STABILITY': 4.24,
 'PRIMER_LEFT_0_GC_PERCENT': 43.47826086956522,
 'PRIMER_LEFT_0_HAIRPIN_TH': 0.0,
 'PRIMER_LEFT_0_PENALTY': 1.11245483566546,
 'PRIMER_LEFT_0_SELF_ANY_TH': 0.0,
 'PRIMER_LEFT_0_SELF_END_TH': 0.0,
 'PRIMER_LEFT_0_SEQUENCE': 'ACAAAGTGGTTCTGGATTAGCTG',
 'PRIMER_LEFT_0_TM': 58.92503010955636,
 'PRIMER_LEFT_1': (54L, 22L),
 'PRIMER_LEFT_1_END_STABILITY': 3.86,
 'PRIMER_LEFT_1_GC_PERCENT': 45.45454545454545,
 'PRIMER_LEFT_1_HAIRPIN_TH': 0.0,
 'PRIMER_LEFT_1_PENALTY': 1.2669303718815925,
 'PRIMER_LEFT_1_SELF_ANY_TH': 0.0,
 'PRIMER_LEFT_1_SELF_END_TH': 0.0,
 'PRIMER_LEFT_1_SEQUENCE': 'AAGTGGTTCTGGATTAGCTGGA',
 'PRIMER_LEFT_1_TM': 59.087044490345306,
 'PRIMER_LEFT_2': (55L, 22L),
 'PRIMER_LEFT_2_END_STABILITY': 3.41,
 'PRIMER_LEFT_2_GC_PERCENT': 45.45454545454545,
 'PRIMER_LEFT_2_HAIRPIN_TH': 0.0,
 'PRIMER_LEFT_2_PENALTY': 1.3141607548431367,
 'PRIMER_LEFT_2_SELF_ANY_TH': 0.0,
 'PRIMER_LEFT_2_SELF_END_TH': 0.0,
 'PRIMER_LEFT_2_SEQUENCE': 'AGTGGTTCTGGATTAGCTGGAT',
 'PRIMER_LEFT_2_TM': 58.88146858768033,
 'PRIMER_LEFT_EXPLAIN': 'considered 507, overlap excluded region 66, GC content failed 60, low tm 128, high tm 78, ok 175',
 'PRIMER_LEFT_NUM_RETURNED': 3L,
 'PRIMER_PAIR_0_COMPL_ANY_TH': 0.0,
 'PRIMER_PAIR_0_COMPL_END_TH': 0.0,
 'PRIMER_PAIR_0_PENALTY': 1.9448563397245948,
 'PRIMER_PAIR_0_PRODUCT_SIZE': 102L,
 'PRIMER_PAIR_1_COMPL_ANY_TH': 0.0,
 'PRIMER_PAIR_1_COMPL_END_TH': 0.0,
 'PRIMER_PAIR_1_PENALTY': 2.0993318759407273,
 'PRIMER_PAIR_1_PRODUCT_SIZE': 99L,
 'PRIMER_PAIR_2_COMPL_ANY_TH': 0.0,
 'PRIMER_PAIR_2_COMPL_END_TH': 0.0,
 'PRIMER_PAIR_2_PENALTY': 2.1465622589022715,
 'PRIMER_PAIR_2_PRODUCT_SIZE': 98L,
 'PRIMER_PAIR_NUM_RETURNED': 3L,
 'PRIMER_RIGHT_0': (152L, 22L),
 'PRIMER_RIGHT_0_END_STABILITY': 3.41,
 'PRIMER_RIGHT_0_GC_PERCENT': 40.90909090909091,
 'PRIMER_RIGHT_0_HAIRPIN_TH': 0.0,
 'PRIMER_RIGHT_0_PENALTY': 0.8324015040591348,
 'PRIMER_RIGHT_0_SELF_ANY_TH': 0.0,
 'PRIMER_RIGHT_0_SELF_END_TH': 0.0,
 'PRIMER_RIGHT_0_SEQUENCE': 'TTCTTGCTGGTGTGAAATGACT',
 'PRIMER_RIGHT_0_TM': 58.44506566396058,
 'PRIMER_RIGHT_1': (152L, 22L),
 'PRIMER_RIGHT_1_END_STABILITY': 3.41,
 'PRIMER_RIGHT_1_GC_PERCENT': 40.90909090909091,
 'PRIMER_RIGHT_1_HAIRPIN_TH': 0.0,
 'PRIMER_RIGHT_1_PENALTY': 0.8324015040591348,
 'PRIMER_RIGHT_1_SELF_ANY_TH': 0.0,
 'PRIMER_RIGHT_1_SELF_END_TH': 0.0,
 'PRIMER_RIGHT_1_SEQUENCE': 'TTCTTGCTGGTGTGAAATGACT',
 'PRIMER_RIGHT_1_TM': 58.44506566396058,
 'PRIMER_RIGHT_2': (152L, 22L),
 'PRIMER_RIGHT_2_END_STABILITY': 3.41,
 'PRIMER_RIGHT_2_GC_PERCENT': 40.90909090909091,
 'PRIMER_RIGHT_2_HAIRPIN_TH': 0.0,
 'PRIMER_RIGHT_2_PENALTY': 0.8324015040591348,
 'PRIMER_RIGHT_2_SELF_ANY_TH': 0.0,
 'PRIMER_RIGHT_2_SELF_END_TH': 0.0,
 'PRIMER_RIGHT_2_SEQUENCE': 'TTCTTGCTGGTGTGAAATGACT',
 'PRIMER_RIGHT_2_TM': 58.44506566396058,
 'PRIMER_RIGHT_EXPLAIN': 'considered 507, overlap excluded region 66, low tm 60, high tm 131, ok 250',
 'PRIMER_RIGHT_NUM_RETURNED': 3L,
 'SEQUENCE_ID': 'R-chr1:114716023-114716228',
 'SEQUENCE_TEMPLATE': 'GTCAGCGGGCTACCACTGGGCCTCACCTCTATGGTGGGATCATATTCATCTACAAAGTGGTTCTGGATTAGCTGGATTGTCAGTGCGCTTTTCCCAACACCACCTGCTCCAACCACCACCAGTTTGTACTCAGTCATTTCACACCAGCAAGAACCTGTTGGAAACCAGTAATCAGGGTTAATTGGCGAGCCACATCTACAGTACT'}
None
```

If I using this,

```
grep -E "PRIMER_LEFT_0_SEQUENCE|PRIMER_LEFT_1_SEQUENCE|PRIMER_RIGHT_0_SEQUENCE|PRIMER_RIGHT_1_SEQUENCE|SEQUENCE_ID" p3out_22_59_3pairs_del_No_out.out | paste - - - - - | awk '{ gsub("\047|,","",$0); print ">"$10"-L0\n"$2"\n>"$10"-L1\n"$4"\n>"$10"-R0\n"$6"\n>"$10"-R1\n"$8}' > xgrep_2primers.out
```

Output is,

```
>R-chr1:114713809-114714010-L0
ATGGCAAATACACAGAGGAAGC
>R-chr1:114713809-114714010-L1
GCAAATACACAGAGGAAGCCTT
>R-chr1:114713809-114714010-R0
AGATGGTGAAACCTGTTTGTTG
>R-chr1:114713809-114714010-R1
AGATGGTGAAACCTGTTTGTTG
```

Can anyone please explain me the meaning of { gsub("\047|,","",$0) in awk? Awk is so powerful tool and I'd like to understand more. If you know good material or place to learn awk tool, please share it with me. Thanks in advance!

Comment: while it may not be perfect, the first result when you search for awk tutorial is generally highly regarded. Did you try looking? Good luck.

Answer (score 4):

the `\047` is an octal escape.  it's actually just a single quote.  when working with embedded quotes, it's sometimes easier to just write `\047` rather than something like `'\''`.

as for `gsub`, it runs the regex `'|,` (the same as `[',]`) and deletes all matches (since the 2nd arg is an empty string).

check out the [POSIX awk documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html) where it describes `gsub` as:

```
gsub(ere, repl[, in])
  Behave like sub (see below), except that it shall replace all
  occurrences of the regular expression (like the ed utility global
  substitute) in $0 or in the in argument, when specified.
```

if you're using `gawk`, check out the [GNU awk manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/).

Answer (score 0):

It's the same as `tr -d "',"`  Delete chars single quote and comma.

Answer (score -1):

Replaces '| with nothing. A bare apostrophe would be the end of a string so is substituted with \047